# Elasticsearch NEST Suggester parser(s) not found

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm attempting to utilize Elasticsearch's '[Suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html)' functionality.

Using Phrase, Term, or Completion I always get the following error variation.

```
unable to parse SuggestionBuilder with name [COMPLETION]: parser not found"
unable to parse SuggestionBuilder with name [TERM]: parser not found"
unable to parse SuggestionBuilder with name [PHRASE]: parser not found"
```

I have tried multiple 6.x NEST versions and they all have the same issue.
Upgrading to 7.0alpha1 does change the error, but seems to cause a myriad of other issues, and I rather not use an alpha library in production.

I'm currently following this tutorial and working it into my existing code: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net-example/tree/6.x-codecomplete-netcore#part-6-suggestions

Currently using NEST 6.1

Model:

```
public class SearchResult {

      public SearchResult()
                {
                    TitleSuggest = new CompletionField {Input = new List<string>(Title.Split(' '))};
                }
                public CompletionField TitleSuggest { get; set; }
        //etc
        }
```

Index Method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateIndex()
        {
            await _searchClient.CreateIndexAsync(SearchIndexName, indexSelector =>
                indexSelector
                    .Mappings(mappingsDescriptor =>
                        mappingsDescriptor.Map<Models.SearchResult>(y => y.AutoMap().Properties(pr=>pr.Completion(c => c.Name(p => p.TitleSuggest)
                        ))))
```

Suggest Method:

```
public async Task<ISearchResponse<SearchResult>> Suggest(string keyword)
        {
return await _searchClient.SearchAsync<SearchResult>(
                s =>
                        s.Suggest(ss => ss
                            .Completion("title", cs => cs
                                .Field(f => f.TitleSuggest)
                                .Prefix(keyword)
                                .Fuzzy(f => f
                                    .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto)
                                )
                                .Size(5))
}
```

I'm having a hard time deciphering the error.
It seems as though the NEST libraries are missing the Suggester parsers?
Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: what version of Elasticsearch are you running against?

Comment: @RussCam Good question. We are using version 6.7.0. I attempted the solution with the latests NEST libraries as well which was 6.6.0. Might be a good idea to sync those up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a follow up, @RussCam answered my question [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/nest-suggester-errors/179634/4)

I had a ConnectionSetting (DefaultFieldNameInferrer) that was uppercasing my suggester

```
private IElasticClient ElasticClient(IConfiguration _config, string defaultIndex)
{
  var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(_config.GetSection("Search:Url").Value))
    .BasicAuthentication(_config.GetSection("Search:User").Value, _config.GetSection("Search:Password").Value)
    .DefaultIndex(_config.GetSection(defaultIndex).Value);
  //settings.DefaultFieldNameInferrer(p => p.ToUpper(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));

  //Enable ElasticSearch Debugging
  settings.PrettyJson().DisableDirectStreaming();

  return new ElasticClient(settings);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var searchResponse = await _searchClient.SearchAsync<SearchResult>(s => s
                .Index(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("index"))
                .Type(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("indextype"))
                .Suggest(su => su
                    .Completion("suggest", cs => cs
                        .Size(20)
                        .Field(f => f.TitleSuggest)
                        .Fuzzy(f => f
                                .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto))
                        .Size(5))));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't appear to have helped. However, I found some interesting info. I adjusted the `Index` and the `Type` methods to be improper values and they didn't affect the error returned. Which might somewhat confirm my initial reaction that this is a deeper issue.

Comment: JFYI Kartheek, you have a spelling error in your profile: "Enigineer".